# SQL: Get value of a column during update

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP and MySQL, I have a query that will look something like this:

```
UPDATE mytable 
   SET status='$newstatus' 
 WHERE (col1='$col1[0]'AND col2='$col2[0]') 
   OR (col1='$col1[1]'AND col2='$col2[1]') 
   OR (...);
```

I actually need to record the current 'status' of each of these rows before the update. Do I need to do a separate SELECT before this, or can (should / how would) I combine the two queries?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. What is your intent ? Your query updates the STATUS column. What else do you want to save ?

Comment: you are already doing what you wanted right?

Comment: Please tell me you're [properly escaping these variables](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because what you're doing here with string interpolation is terrifying.

Comment: They are safe strings. No user data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get that from this query (you could only get number of affected rows, but that's it). If you need that, you shall first do `SELECT` on your conditions like:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `mytable`
WHERE (`col1`='$col1[0]' AND `col2`='$col2[0]')
   OR (`col1`='$col1[1]' AND `col2`='$col2[1]')
   OR (...)
```

and then do `UPDATE` with `WHERE` using fetched `id`s. I do not recommend doing `UPDATE` with your current `WHERE` clause as in meantime (between your `SELECT` and `UPDATE`) db content could change, so you could be UPDATING different rows that you had `SELECT`ed. Or use table locking (but I do not think it makes sense here).

Comment: After I posted the question, I found a near duplicate and saw that OUTPUT exists in some SQL flavors, but not MySQL. I came up with the same answer you did. Fortunately I already had my entier WHERE clause in a seperate variable so I just did a SELECT before the UPDATE. Not tested yet, but the logic seem right.

Comment: `WHERE` clause in variable or not makes no difference. the issue I flagged is based on concurrent database access. It is quite likely (and you shall always assume it will happen in 100%) that once you do the `SELECT` other process will do i.e. `INSERT` or `DELETE` or `UPDATE` that would affect rows matching your criteria. So when you do your `UPDATE` you in fact will change different rows that you got from your former `SELECT`. That may look bit tricky, but ignoring this could lead to database inconsistency.

Comment: Oh,  I see. I didn't consider that because it's an infrequently updated DB, but certainly makes good sense as a BestPractices rule.

Answer (score 1):

No `OUTPUT` clause in Mysql. You need to either read status prior to update or create a trigger that stores value of `OLD.status` in other table.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "create a trigger"? I am not familiar with that expression in this context.

Comment: Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html for complete syntax; if you want to store old value in a separate table (say, `mytable_status_history`), you will need an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger on `mytable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a single query to update the row and record the current status before updating.

You'd better have a "log table", with the same schema of your "table" plus a **timestamp**, but it would store only  historical data, the status of a row in a single point in time, like a versioning system.

**Example:**

Table **User**: Id, Username, Email, Telephone

Table **UserLog**: Id, Username, Email, Telephone, **Timestamp**

So, before updating a row on table User, you'd first do a SELECT and an INSERT, like this:

```
insert into UserLog
select Id, Username, Email, Telephone, Now()  from User where Id=$Id
```